# why is my sub-task being killed in ant task?

Tags: shell, process, solaris, ant

I'm using Ant which basically is a java program to start up a ksh (test.ksh) script on Solaris.  Inside this ksh, calling another ksh (test1.ksh) script which start up a program and I wish this program can keep running.

Ant target just looks like this:

```
    <target name="start.loading.data.Global">
    <shellscript shell="ksh">./test.ksh</shellscript>
    <sleep seconds="300"/>
    </target>
```

The problem is I found when ant target finish, the program has been killed.
I've confirm it by adding

```
    <sleep seconds="300"/>
```

because from my app's log, it can run about 3 mins and after I added sleep, it can run about 8 mins.

I have tried using

```
    <parallel>
```

in ant script but didn't work.
I also tried to use nohup to start up ksh but didn't work.

Any suggestions?
If possible, please also explain how a shell works.

Comment: Although your question is technically on-topic on [unix.se], it seems to be mostly about Ant, which is a build tool and for which [so] has more expertise. So your question has been moved to [so].

Comment: It sounds to me like your shell script test1.ksh is completing and not running indefinately as you are expecting. Perhaps you should post up the code in shell scripts, or explain some more what you're trying to do. From your description so far seems to be a shell problem.

Comment: have you tried adding `&` at the end of the ksh filename : `<shellscript shell="ksh">./test.ksh &</shellscript>`, it's a long shot but maybe it will work.

Answer (score 0):

shellscript task is just an extension of the exec ant task and according to the [documentation](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/shellscript.html), it can use all the same properties.  You may need add spawn=true which is one of the [exec](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) properties, to your shellscript task like this:

```
<shellscript shell="ksh" spawn="true">./test.ksh</shellscript>
```

Spawn=true should cause the shell script to be set up as a separate process and be able to live on after the java/ant process has completed.